# Show date of friday every 2 weeks

Tags: php, wordpress, date, woocommerce, dateinterval

I have woocommerce products with special pickup dates. Pickup day is on fridays. For example a products has a pickup time in two weeks, the date i want to show by the product should be:

- 31-07-2020
- 14-08-2020
- 28-08-2020
  (every two weeks)

What my code below do is:

- 31-07-2020
- **07-08-2020 WRONG**
  (this is not every two weeks then, because it counts then from the next friday)

Here i calculate the dates:

```
function lwb_pickup_days( $att ) {
    
    switch ( $att ) {
        case "weekly":
            $date = date_i18n( 'l, d.m.Y', strtotime("next Friday"));
            return $date;
            break;
        case "2 weeks":
            $date = date_i18n( 'l, d.m.Y', strtotime("next Friday + 2weeks"));
            return $date;
            break;
        case "3 weeks":
            $date = date_i18n( 'l, d.m.Y', strtotime("next Friday + 3weeks"));
            return $date;
            break;
        case "4 weeks":
            $date = date_i18n( 'l, d.m.Y', strtotime("next Friday + 4weeks"));
            return $date;
            break;      
    }       
}
```

This is how i use the function above to get the pickup date for each product!

```
// Show Attributes on Product Archive & Single Product
function lwb_show_attribute_on_product(){
    global $product;
    
    $taxonomy = 'pa_lieferfrequenz';
    $value = $product->get_attribute( $taxonomy );
    
    // calculate the pickup date
    $date = lwb_pickup_days( $value );

    if ( $value ) {
        $label = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name;
        $name = 'Abholtag';
        echo '<div class="lwb-product-meta">';
            echo '<p class="lwb-' . strtolower( $label ) .'">' . $name . ': ' . $date . '</p>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'lwb_show_attribute_on_product', 45 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_start', 'lwb_show_attribute_on_product', 45 );
```

Thanks for your inputs...

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on the problem, but can you try just taking out the word **next** from all of them? "Next Friday" always means next Friday (so if it's already Friday then it means in one week). "Friday" will resolve to today if it's already Friday, and otherwise be the next one. Which I *think* is what you're asking for.

Comment: for example: upcoming friday is 17-07-2020 for a product with delivery time + 2 weeks (the delivery date will be 31-07-2020) - then the problem is one week later the delivery date for this product will be the 07-08-2020 because my code starts counting from friday always

the right delivery dates should be:
31-07
13-08
27-08
.....
.....
.....

i hope this clarifys a bit, what i mean

Comment: Hi, sorry maybe its me being dense, but I am not sure what the problem is you are asking us to help with. Can you show  some inputs with the expected outputs and then what your code is doing that is wrong

Comment: edited OP to clarify

Comment: No. :) How about ... I pass `$att="2 weeks"` and I want the date `xx-xx-xxxx` but it is giving me the date `yy-yy-yyyy`

Comment: tried to clarify again in OP

Comment: Your code can't accomplish this without more information - it can't know that sometimes "next Friday + 2 weeks" is ok, but other times it isn't. You need to either provide it with an anchor point (a valid Friday so that you can iterate from there), or more logic (every 1st and 3rd Friday of the month are valid, etc)

Comment: how can i achieve this with an anchor point? i know the problem, but i dont know how to fix this... do you have any inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
// this Friday.
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('friday this week'))

// in 2 weeks
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('friday this week') + 7 * 2 * 86400)

// in 4 weeks
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('friday this week') + 7 * 4 * 86400)

// etc
```